# 'Platform' object has no attribute 'add_internal'

Tags: python, pygame

I have again stumbled across a problem in my Pygame project. In trying to create a group for my platforms, which will aid in coding environmental collision, I am getting the error:

```
'Platform' object has no attribute 'add_internal'
```

I have created a group:

```
platforms=pygame.sprite.Group()
ground=GameClass.Platform(0,500,500,40)
platforms.add(ground)
```

The ground variable is assigned to the class 'Platform' in the separate file 'GameClass':

```
class Platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,w,h):
        self._x=x
        self._y=y
        self._w=w
        self._h=h

        pygame.draw.rect(display,BLACK,[self._x,self._y,self._w,self._h])
```

The group creation code resides above the game loop, so it is only run once.

Thanks,
Link

Answer (score 1):

You can only add instances of [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) subclasses to a `pygame.sprite.Group`. You also have to call the `__init__` method of the superclass: `super().__init__()` (or `super(Platform, self).__init__()` in Python 2).

```
class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,w,h):
        super().__init__()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it - your `Platform` class is missing the `add_internal` method which is defined in the [Sprite class](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/src/48e19c7b9ee902f54a7973d70394d2bea79c1fa5/lib/sprite.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#sprite.py-162).

You need to make the `Platform` class to be `Sprite` subclass: `class Platform(Sprite): ...`.

Comment: (and call pygame.sprite.Sprite's `__init__`)